# script en PHP para instalar Node.js

Tags: php, nodejs, linux, script, hosting

Hola  quiero saber si es posible preparar un script en PHP para instalar Node.js y algunas dependencias y luego iniciar un servidor hecho en Node.js en un hosting que esta limitado a PHP.

Comment: Hola, ¿qué significa *un servidor hecho en Node.js*? ¿No será una aplicación o programa hecho en Node.js? El servidor es el hosting, y si no te permite usar Node.js, no podrás instalar Node.js de ningún modo. Pero ¿seguro que tu hosting no admite Node.js? Si es así, entonces cambia a un hosting que sí te permita usar Node.js.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar[ask],saludos.

Comment: `<?php mail('administrador@hosting', 'Necesito Node.js', 'Me instala el node? Gracias'); ?>`  btw la aplicación mas común en node.js es un servidor web usando `node:http` o el menos engorroso `express`